# How filter posts by Year on Wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

How to filter posts by year, by a custom field?

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'movies',
    'showposts'   => '28',
    'meta_value' => array( 'release_date' =>  '2021-09-01', ),          );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need something along the meta query lines:
See [WP_Meta_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/)

```
$args = array(
              'post_type' => 'movies',
              'post_status' => 'publish',
              'posts_per_page' => -1,
              'orderby'   => 'release_date',
              'order'     => 'ASC',
              'meta_query'  => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                  'key'   => 'release_date',
                  'value'     => '2021-09-01',
                  'compare'   => '=',
                  'type' => 'DATE'
                ),
              )
            );
```

Comment: with your help i a add 2 arrays, to start and end date, and found the solution, thank you my friend!!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the global `$wpdb` to execute your custom DB query.

It should be something like that:

`SELECT p.ID, m.meta_value as post_year FROM wp_posts p INNER JOIN wp_postmeta m ON (p.ID = m.post_id and m.meta_key = 'release_date') WHERE p.post_type = 'movies' and 'publish' ORDER BY m.meta_value DESC;`

And on the PHP side you may use something like code below:

`global $wpdb;`

`$results = $wpdb->get_results( $query, 'ARRAY_A' );`

Or use `WP_Meta_Query`. But i believe that it might be resolved as simple DB-request without extra helper classes.

if you know mysql well you will able to customize that request easily for your aims.

Wish you luck.